# SQLite3 apply substring to BLOB

Tags: sqlite, substring, blob, substr

I have a field that contains two values, separated by a coma and stored as BLOB, such as en these examples:

```
values
13,0
0,120
192,12
```

I am trying to create a `SELECT` query which only spits out the value on the right side of the comma.

I would need to cast the values-BLOB into a string in order to be able to apply `instr()` and `substr()`. How should I do that? Can somebody help my out?

Comment: Which part of the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) do you not understand?

Comment: Many parts @CL. How is BLOB to behave upon a substr function, for example? The only thing I find is:" If X is a BLOB then the indices refer to bytes.", So how would I choose the correct index - I just don't, which then again is why I ask

Answer (score 0):

In ASCII text, bytes *are* characters.

However, if you want to cast a blob value into a string, use a [CAST expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr):

```
SELECT substr(CAST(MyBlob AS TEXT), ...) ...
```

Comment: I have actually tried something similar to that, but all I get as output us an 'x'. The command `select substr(cast(gt_alt_depths as TEXT),0,2) from variants`. If I change the index to 1,2, for example, I get an error that says: `SQLite error: Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'substr(cast(gt_alt_depths as TEXT), 1, 2)' with text 'x�'`

Comment: Then what you said about the contents of the blobs is not correct. Show the output of `SELECT hex(gt_alt_depths) FROM ...`.

Comment: If I open the .db file with the graphical interface, it says that the field is of type blob. The entry looks like this, if `hex()` is applied: 78DA6B604ACE2BCD2DA8D44BCE2F4AD5CB2DCD29C94C2C2A4AACE48A2F4A4DCECF2B2E292A4D2EE12A6484A8E2CA4B81C816327933B4863226B50715326B78337A33B54215A4945416A47215B28432659A783378330215B06A78338732DAF8F9F979FD070230E1CD5092D419CAC1C8C0C0C006C425497A000FFB2EF3

Comment: This is not "two values, separated by a coma".

Comment: The format, when output as a whole (string) looks like this, for example `14,18`.

Comment: Why do you say that they are not values separated by a coma? @CL.

Comment: Because that blob is something else. It's probably compressed.